# Best blogging platform for use on AFS space

Tags: wordpress, drupal, content-management-system, blogs

I need to create a blog for my student organization at my university, and we have access to a folder on the school's AFS system. We would like to install a CMS such as WordPress or Drupal and then interface with that via a blogging client to streamline updating the website. We can My only experience with any CMS is developing an Android app that connects to a Drupal powered blog, so I'm familiar with some of its features.

Any thoughts on the best way to go about creating this blog?

Answer (score 0):

Drupal has 2 core modules that can help you with this, [Blog](http://drupal.org/documentation/modules/blog) and [Blog API](http://drupal.org/documentation/modules/blogapi).  Using both of these modules, you will be able to update blogs on your Drupal site through a blogging client.

Another Drupal user has created a video about blogging with Drupal's Blog and Blog API which you can see [HERE](http://gotdrupal.com/videos/using-drupal-blog-software-for-blogging).

Answer (score 0):

"Best" is always super subjective.

If what you want is a standard, robust blog functionality quickly with minimal learning curve, you want Word Press. If what you want is a flexible, robust blog functionality with room to scale out and add more functionality over time you might want to make the *larger* and *slower* investment of going with Drupal.

Speaking as a Drupal Developer myself, I would reach for Drupal because I favor building with future flexibility in mind, but then I've already defeated the learning curve.